# Flip Animation is not consistant in size between front and back images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, core-animation, uiimage

using the same flip animation as in the Elements, I have a view controller flipping two .png files of the same size (640 x 960)  Within each image I have drawn a border and have noticed that when I flip the image, the second image gets stretched slightly downward and you no longer see the bottom border.

I've checked my .xib file where I have two views and an imageview inside each view.  The imageviews are both the same size and have the same settings.  I did notice that in interface builder the size for the layout is 320 X 460.  Note that the first view appears in its entirety and as I flip it over and over it continues to appear as it should and the other image is clipped.

Comment: After more testing, I commented out my removefromsuperview on the tap so that the same view is displayed on both sides of the flip.  The image remained intact.  I am deducing that the backside view is clipping the image.  I still don't have a resolution as to why the image is being clipped in the second view.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the first view presented to the window has a heeight of 416 and not 480 as expected.  I forgot to account for the added NavBar and the initial view squashed my image to fit in its entirety.  I have since set the view size in the back view and am dealing with the smaller image area.